# Experience calculation

Tags: c#

I get the date from the user in given format(dd.mm.yy) for the date of joining.From the given date i have to calculate the experience of the person.

```
try
{
    _doj = DateTime.Parse(Console.ReadLine(console.ReadLine()_dataformat,null));
    if (_doj <= DateTime.today)
        break;//I have given the breakpoint here and _doj value is 01/20/2015(actually given input is 20.04.2015)
    else
        Console.WriteLine("The date is exsisttodaysdate:"); 
}
catch
{
    Console.WriteLine("please enter valid date:");
}
```

So please help me for getting the output.

Comment: Sorry but the question doesn't make sense to me. What do you mean by "getting the output"?

Comment: You are probably having problems because you don't have the correct culture set.   My guess would be your PC is running in (say) US timezone/culture but the way you type in your date (with dots not slashes) suggests you are in Europe somewhere.

Comment: Actually im getting the input from the user as(20.09.2018) dd.mm.yyyy in this format.And then when i print the date user's date it is printing in 01/20/2018.My question is why the date is not printed as userinput format and month value always printed as 01.Since im new please help me..

Answer (score 1):

If I understood it correctly, then you want to subtract two dates. Subtraction of two dates can be archived by `DateTime.Subtract()` function.

```
var totalDays = DateTime.Today.Subtract(oldDate).TotalDays;
```

From `totalDays`, you can calculate an experience.

[DateTime Subtract](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ysw4sby(v=vs.110).aspx)

Proof of work: [DotNetFiddler](https://dotnetfiddle.net/XPjwhs)

Comment: Actually im getting the input from the user as(20.09.2018) dd.mm.yyyy in this format.And then when i print the date user's date it is printing in 01/20/2018.My question is why the date is not printed as userinput format and month value always printed as 01.Since im new please help me..

Answer (score 1):

You may need to define the format that you want to parse. You can use [ParseExact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx) method by passing format parameter:

```
var _doj = DateTime.ParseExact(Console.ReadLine(), "dd.MM.yyyy", 
new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US"));
```